# My cookie is not displayed in my response React Axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, axios

I know the subject is discussed a thousand times, but I've tried every solution and still nothing.

React Axios:

```
async login(email: string, password: string) {
        return await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }, {
            withCredentials: true, headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(response => {
            return response
        }).catch(error => {
            return error.response
        })
    }
```

Backend

```
app.use(cors({
    exposedHeaders: "Authorization",
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000"
}))

res.cookie('sessionUser', token, {
                        maxAge: 7200,
                        httpOnly: true,
                        secure: true,
                        sameSite: "none"
                    })
```

Comment: Cookies might be included in the set cookie header, but they wont even do that in this case as you set it to httpOnly.

Comment: @Dan But httpOnly is a question of security, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `httpOnly` set in your cookie. HTTP only cookies are only sent on a request made by the browser to the same origin as the page - they aren't accessible via Javascript. So in this case your cookie is being sent to the server (this is what `withCredentials: true` does if I recall) but you won't be able to access it from the JS.

What details do you need from the cookie? It's generally recommended to store sensitive cookies as HTTPOnly - if you just need to pass non secure data back from the cookie then you could return it from your `login` endpoint as JSON maybe? If you are returning a token or something sensitive instead that you will need for future requests then I would keep that in your HttpOnly cookie as long as all the requests will be to the same domain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies